# hover on element with jquery only when hover on his container

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
<ul class="accordion" id="accordion">

                <li class="bg4">
                    <div class="heading">fdgfdg</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>fdgdf</h2>
                        <p>dfgdfg</p>
                        <a href="#">fdgdfg&rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="bg5 bleft">
                    <div class="heading">מגדל מטלון</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>ffg</h2>
                        <p></p>
                        <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

And I have this code

```
 $(function () {
                $('#accordion > li').hover(



                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({ 'width': '480px' }, 500);
                        $('.heading', $this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
                        $('.bgDescription', $this).stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
                        $('.description', $this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
                    },
                    function () {

                            var $this = $(this);
                            $this.stop().animate({ 'width': '122px' }, 500);
                            $('.heading', $this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
                            $('.description', $this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
                            $('.bgDescription', $this).stop(true, true).slideUp(700);

                    }
                );
                    });
```

right now when hover on one of the `<li>` is width is growing (and shrink when unhover)

Is there a way that the `<li>` unhover code will excute only if I hover on other `li` and when The container(the `<ul>`) loose focus it will stay the same size withot excuting the unhover code?

Comment: when do you want them to collapse? is there any time you do want them all to collapse or after one is chose and opened it always stays open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you only wanted to collapse the items when some other external condition is met, so I used a button.

Assuming you only want one open at a time, I agree with Milind Ansatwar that you need to watch the mouse enterevent of the li's.

You change only the items that were not this item:

```
    $('#accordion > li').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $others = $('#accordion > li').not($this);

        $this.stop().animate({
            'width': '480px'
        }, 500);
        $('.heading', $this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        $('.bgDescription', $this).stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
        $('.description', $this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();

        $others.stop().animate({
            'width': '122px'
        }, 500);
        $('.heading', $others).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        $('.description', $others).stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
        $('.bgDescription', $others).stop(true, true).slideUp(700);
    });
```

Now when you move over the items you never trigger a mouse out or a 'dehover' and so they stay open all the time until you enter another li.

I added a button to collapse the items in case it is undesirable to have them open all the time.

[Here is a working demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/3yVLU/6/)

[Ok 15th time is the charm:](http://jsfiddle.net/3yVLU/15/)

I modified the code so that the place holder is not used and instead you are changing the way that the header is positioned. This effectively eliminates the dance:

```
    $('#accordion > li').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $others = $('#accordion > li').not($this);

        $this.stop().animate({
            'width': '480px'
        }, 500);
        $('.heading', $this).stop(true, true).css('position','absolute').fadeOut('500');
        $('.description', $this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();

        $others.stop().animate({
            'width': '122px'
        }, 500);
        $('.description', $others).stop(true, true).fadeOut(500,function(){
            $('.heading', $others).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
            $('.heading', $others).css('position','static');
        });              
    });
```

it also eliminates a bit of the jumping the rows did but not all of it. I mean after all you are collapsing the row so it is going to jump out from under the mouse.

Comment: I am still working on it though. If you check the fiddle and go to the bottom of the top element then just barely move into the bottom element, you will see an amazing dance. I am working on fixing that.

Comment: it is fixed now, but not exactly what you had. I am not sure if the change I made is going to amiable to other scripts you may have that depends on the previous behavior.

Comment: I can't see the dance you are talking about ,thanks man for the great effort

Answer (score 2):

Follow this:

1)What you can do is,you can check the width on mouseenter of that element.

2)then you need to get all `$('#accordion > li')` and make their width to 122pixels

3)and increase the width of current hovered(using `$(this)`) to 480pixels.

Comment: I tried this already the problem starts when you move the mouse to quickly from one li to another.

Comment: @baaroz:what problem are you getting when you do that??

Comment: I think I know: when you sit at the right spot at the bottom of the top element, the elements push into each other and create a this flickering dance. I am working on fixing it in my fiddle right now. I am assuming this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move the "unhover" function as an uside one and call it on every li hover. Also call it only on ul "dehover".

Comment: I do I know which li to close when I move it out